# .htaccess port 80 to another port SEO impact?

Tags: seo, htaccess, ghost-blog

I am using the Ghost blogging platform. By default to access the blog you go to `blog.my-site.com:2368` of course this makes for a ugly, unfriendly URL. I am using *.htaccess* to change the behavior so when a person types in `blog.my-site.com` they see the URL.

I used the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mywebsite.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.mywebsite.com:2368%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

From my understanding this is not a redirect, but rather transparently sends the traffic from port 80 to port 2368.

My question is this:

Does this process have any impact on SEO or, in the views of SEO, it is the same as `blog.my-site.com`?

Comment: Matt Cutts on different ports and Google: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wO-1zvXgzg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [P fla](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)g causes the request to be handled by [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html), essentially replacing the "ugly" URL with the more friendly one for both users and search engine bots.

This would likely improve recognition and the likelihood of users clicking on the URL, so in short it would be good for your website's traffic, and certainly not negatively impact your SEO. Much of the links and content you see in search engines are the result of proxies and servers working on different ports in the background, unbeknownst to the client (including bots).

Comment: Thanks for the information! This is a new area for me as I am mainly Front End person. `.htaccess` and what it contains is foreign to me so I always want to ensure everything is okay. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem Lynda - as always, great feedback :-)